# Vim undo: undo changes after file write

Tags: vim, undo

In my code on vim, I did a lot of changes and then did a `ZZ` (save and exit). But then I realized I didn't need those changes. Is there a way I can get back to the state before doing those changes using from some buffer where that data still might be stored. I haven't made any changes after the save & exit.

Comment: Restore from a backup.

Comment: @choroba , precisely, that's what I need to know, how do I do that?

Comment: Do you have persistent undo turned on? (Most likely not but its on option worth looking into for future use) Take a look at `:h persistent-undo`

Comment: @FDinoff : I didn't had that ON, just now added the following in my .vimrc:
`set undofile`
`set undodir=/home/<uname>/.vimundo/`

Comment: If you don't see a filename~ previous version of the file in the directory, your .vimrc may have bdir or backupdir set to something like ~/.vimbackup

Answer (score 61, accepted):

There's **persistent undo** option in vim, `:h persistent-undo`
**Note:** It was introduced in VIM 7.3 version, so for earlier versions, it will not work.

It can be turned on by placing the following text in your `.vimrc`:

```
if has('persistent_undo')      "check if your vim version supports it
  set undofile                 "turn on the feature  
  set undodir=$HOME/.vim/undo  "directory where the undo files will be stored
endif
```

**Note:** Before enabling this option, whatever was lost, remains lost.
After enabling the option, you will be able to do subsequent undo/redo on whatever was added/deleted after enabling the option.

Comment: Notice that you have to make sure the directory exists to make it work.

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer was accepted. I have the same situation as asked in the question, but I still don't understand how it solves the problem. The setting seems to work only for new files/changes.

Comment: You can make sure the directory exists by adding a statement `silent !mkdir -p ~/.vim/undo` inside the if-block. This solution assumes you have write permissions to create the directory `~/.vim/undo`.